# How to get parent recordtype name from child object id through inline vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to get the parent Recordtype Name from Child Object Id (while creating a new child record through child object Inline visualforce page on parent object ) in apex and render field using parent record type Name on child object inline visualforce page.

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] your question to include the Visualforce page as well as the controller or controller extension that you are using.

Comment: if I have to display Account's record type in Contact page, I would use relationship like objContact.Account.Name in page

Comment: Either pull it in using a formulafield on the object. Otherwise you will need a controller and query for it which since you are creating a new record you will have to do

Comment: You must be able to achieve this using relationships. Child__c[] childApx = [SELECT id, Name, Account.RecordType.Name from Child__c where id=:childId];  On VFPage, assign child to a vf variable(child) and access child.Account.RecordType.Name

Answer (score -1):

Since you will be having visualforce page on parent page, it should have standard controller of standard object you should be able to access the recordtype using the parent object name itself like ParentObject.RecordType